# How to Create a Makefile to comile a C file and Java File Separately

Tags: java, c, makefile

I am new to creating makefiles with java files and c files together.  I am trying to just have the two files compiled separately by using one makefile.  The clean commands don't seem to be an issue, but the below code only compiles the C file.

What am I missing?

```
#target: dependencies

helloWorld: helloWord.c
        g++ -std=c++0x helloWorld.c -o helloWorld

hi.class: hi.java
        javac hi.java

clean:
        rm helloWorld
        rm hi.class
```

Comment: You're missing a unifying dependency. Something needs to be dependent on *both* `helloWorld` and `hi.class`. I think some time in the [make docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) may be a worthwhile endeavor.

Comment: Why do you expect this to compile the java file? I think you need to read a basic tutorial about Makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it will only build the first target. Option 1, add an "all" before `helloWorld` like (also, there's a typo on your version of `helloWorld`).

```
all: helloWorld hi.class

helloWorld: helloWorld.c
    g++ -std=c++0x helloWorld.c -o helloWorld
```

Or, you can explicitly run your existing target

```
make hi.class
```